# Bootstrap-toggle button not working properly in a partial view

Tags: asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, partial-views, togglebutton

Boostrap toggle button doesn't work on the first attempt after being loaded on a partial view but works on the second attempt

When I click on the First Record of the dropdown menu the toggle button doesn't work, when I click on the Second Record the toggle works, and in the Third Record, it doesn't work. But if I reload the page and click on the second record it doesn't do anything and if I click on the first record it magically works. Any suggestions!

```
<select name="speed" onchange="showCharts(this)" style="outline: none ;width: 
        100%;border-radius: 3px; height: 35px;color: darkgray;padding-left: 
        5px; border: 0.1em solid lightgray;">
    <option disabled selected>Type of Chart</option>
    <option value="1">First Record</option>
    <option value="2">SecondRecord</option>
    <option value="3">Third Record</option>

</select>

<div class=" " id="collapseOne"></div>
```

```
    function showCharts(s) {
        switch (s[s.selectedIndex].value) {
            case "1":
                 $('#collapseOne').load('@Url.Action("1record", "Home")');
                break;
            case "2":
                 $('#collapseOne').load('@Url.Action("2record", "Home")');
                break;
            case "3":
                 $('#collapseOne').load('@Url.Action("3record", "Home")');
                break;
        }
}
```

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult 1record()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult 2record()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult 3record()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "# Record";

}

<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
```

[image: toggle-button]

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind I made a workaround, adding a partial view with only a toggle button to the javascript like such:

```
function showCharts(s) {
    switch (s[s.selectedIndex].value) {
        case "1":
             $('#collapseOne').load('@Url.Action("empty", "Home")');
             $('#collapseOne').load('@Url.Action("1record", "Home")');
            break;
        case "2":
             $('#collapseOne').load('@Url.Action("empty", "Home")');
             $('#collapseOne').load('@Url.Action("2record", "Home")');
            break;
        case "3":
             $('#collapseOne').load('@Url.Action("empty", "Home")');
            $('#collapseOne').load('@Url.Action("3record", "Home")');
            break;
    }
}
```

create a partial view with only one toggle button
then add the partial view to your controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult empty()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved to this way:

I called its function in partial view.

```
<input id="my-toggle" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked data-size="small"/>

<script>
    $('#my-toggle').bootstrapToggle();
</script>
```